# Manage multiple progress view in collection view cells Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

In my app i have a collection view,the cell have an image and button. the UIImage represent a book the user want to download. When the user clicked on the **button** in the cell i should show a progress view that represent the download progress. 
my cell is a **Nib**.
My problem is in the managing of the progress view in all this cell.
when i clicked on a cell the progress bar shown in another cell!! 
any one try to do something like that before?
**Edited1**: 
my cellForItemAtIndexPath is :

```
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("guides-cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GuidesViewCell
       cell.guidesTypeLabel.text = guidesArray[indexPath.item].Title
       cell.downloadLink = guidesArray[indexPath.item].Download1          
       cell.downloadButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: "downlaodAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       cell.downloadButtonOutlet.tag = indexPath.row
```

**Edited2**:

i try to call the download function form the **cell class**, i take an action outlet of the button, and i call download function from it.
like this :

```
  @IBAction func downloadButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {



    FileIsdownloding = true
    downloadActivityIndicator.alpha = 1
    downloadActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    downloadProgressBar.alpha = 1
    DownloadpdfsFilesControllerVar.downloadPDFFile(downloadLink, view:self, progressBarVar: downloadProgressBar, senderButton: sender as! UIButton)



}
```

I still have the same problem. The progress bar was showed i random cells!!!!
that's awful!

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: seems like you don't reuse the collection view cell in a right way. can you show the codes of cellForIndexPath?

Comment: See "Best Practices in Progress Reporting" from WWDC 2015. They demonstrate this exact issue, along with a fully working sample project. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=232 (Your specific issue of using the wrong cell probably means you're vending and configuring cells incorrectly and is unrelated to progress reporting, but the sample project will show how to do that correctly as well.)

Comment: @Kevin i edit my question

Comment: @RobNapier thank you :) i'll check ur link for sure

Comment: @RobNapier i edited my question, can u check it please? 
i'll be so thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.downloadButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: "downlaodAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

A cell pulled from `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` may already have been used before.

`addTarget(action:forControlEvents:)` *adds* a target. It doesn't remove the old ones. You need to include:

```
cell.downloadButtonOutlet.removeTarget(nil)
```

to clear out the old target. Your current code is probably calling the action for every target that this cell has ever been used for.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but where should i add it ? 
in the cellForItems?

Comment: Yes, in the block that configures the cell. Read over the Table View Programming Guide for guidance on how cells are vended and configured. (Collection Views follow almost the same architecture as Table Views.) https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: thanks so mush. 
but i have 2 question:
1- how i add a target in the cellForItems and at the same time i remove it! 
2- why i still have the problem if i call  "downlaodAction" from the cell class?

Comment: The cell you are using has already been configured. It's a *reusable* cell. It's been used before. You must first remove the old configuration settings (like the old target), and set a new one. Similarly, you must make sure that each cell is correctly configured to point to the right progress indicator, etc.  You probably have other cell properties that you're setting somewhere else and not replacing correctly when the cell is reused.